# ¿Cómo serializar un objeto que internamente tenga una lista de objetos en json? C#

Tags: c#, json, c#-8.0, .net-5

tengo un problema y es que necesito serializar un objeto pero el problema es que dentro de mi clase del objeto que quiero serializar tiene una lista de objetos, acá les dejo mi clase principal:

```
[Serializable]
public class Equipo
{

    public List<Jugador> jugadores;
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public String Capitan { get; set; }
    public int Puntos { get; set; }
}
```

Como podemos ver, hay una lista de objeto de tipo Jugador, ahora, cuando serializo mi objeto sucede esto:

```
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, GetJsonSerializerOptions());
```

Y el código se mira de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podemos ver, faltó serializar la lista jugadores, lo que se me ocurrió fue serializar por partes, entonces serialicé la lista de objetos por aparte y luego combiné todo:

```
    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, GetJsonSerializerOptions());
    string listjson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jugadores, GetJsonSerializerOptions());
    string newString = "{\n \"jugadores\": " + listjson + "," + json[1..];
```

como quedó:

```
{
 "jugadores": [
  {
    "Nombre": "Antonio",
    "Champ": "Sova",
    "Muertes": 0,
    "Asesinatos": 0,
    "Asistencias": 0
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Antonio",
    "Champ": "Sova",
    "Muertes": 0,
    "Asesinatos": 0,
    "Asistencias": 0
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Antonio",
    "Champ": "Sova",
    "Muertes": 0,
    "Asesinatos": 0,
    "Asistencias": 0
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Antonio",
    "Champ": "Sova",
    "Muertes": 0,
    "Asesinatos": 0,
    "Asistencias": 0
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Antonio",
    "Champ": "Sova",
    "Muertes": 0,
    "Asesinatos": 0,
    "Asistencias": 0
  }
],
  "Nombre": "dada",
  "Puntos": 0
}
```

Yo pensaría que funcionaría pero al momento de deserializar el objeto:

> JsonSerializer.Deserialize(bytes, GetJsonSerializerOptions());

Se rescata todos los valores menos la lista de Jugadores.
Lo que se me ocurriría sería crear un nuevo objeto de Equipo y combinar las 2 partes, pero por las circunstancia no podré hacer eso.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: La lista no tiene get y set, no la va a serializar nunca... aparte, si le pasas el tipo de objeto a serializar, funciona mejor... tu clase deberia funcionar de una sin ningun tipo de workaround....

Comment: @gbianchi Muchísimas gracias, tienes toda la razón, error mío, no vi esa parte, muchas gracias de nuevo, funcionó.